# I need to manage state for each tab in react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.js. Can you please help me with below code in which I need to manage the state for each tab?

```
state = {
    selected: false
}
handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({
        selected: true
    })
}

render (){
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className={styles.tabsResultsTabs}>
                <li onClick={this.handleChangeTab} className={this.state.selected ? styles.active : null}>Home</li>    
                <li onClick={this.handleChangeTab} className={this.state.selected ? styles.active : null} id="2">Post</li>
                <li onClick={this.handleChangeTab} className={this.state.selected ? styles.active : null} id="3">Contact us</li>
                <li onClick={this.handleChangeTab} className={this.state.selected ? styles.active : null} id="4">About</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Above code is not working. So, I need the style should get toggle between the active tab when I clicked.

Comment: Have a look at react-router. This might be apt for your case

Comment: @MonicaAcha How?

Comment: Hi Saumitra, just wrote you an answer, let me know if that helps you out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tophergates/jb3jkxww/ Have a look at this to navigate between components using react routers

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
  selected: 0
}
handleChangeTab = (i) => {
this.setState({
  selected: i
})
}

render ()
{
return (
<div>
<ul className={styles.tabsResultsTabs}>

<li onClick={()=>this.handleChangeTab(0)} className={this.state.selected===0 ? styles.active : null}>Home</li>

<li onClick={()=>this.handleChangeTab(1)} className={this.state.selected===1 ? styles.active : null} id="2">Post</li>

<li onClick={()=>this.handleChangeTab(2)} className={this.state.selected===2 ? styles.active : null} id="3">Contact us</li>

<li onClick={()=>this.handleChangeTab(3)} className={this.state.selected===3 ? styles.active : null} id="4">About</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

I'm not sure my answer is recommendable, but I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a few ways. I think it would make sense to have a state-value for each tab. That opens up the possibility of having more functionality.

**Things I added:**

- A state-value for each tab in our component state.
- A name property for each tab in our mark-up that matches with one in
  our state.
- An event-handler, it will find the name of the tab that was clicked
  and dynamically find a key in our component state with a matching
  name. This will allow us to toggle active and inactive tabs.

Here is the code-sandbox as well so you can test it: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-lewin-1vl6z

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    home: false,
    post: false,
    contact: false,
    about: false
  };

  handleChangeTab = event => {
    let tabName = (event.target.getAttribute("name"));
    let initialState = {
      home: false,
      post: false,
      contact: false,
      about: false
    };

    this.setState({
      ...initialState,
      [tabName]: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li
            onClick={this.handleChangeTab}
            className={this.state.home ? "active" : null}
            name="home"
          >
            Home
          </li>
          <li
            onClick={this.handleChangeTab}
            className={this.state.post ? "active" : null}
            name="post"
          >
            Post
          </li>
          <li
            onClick={this.handleChangeTab}
            className={this.state.contact ? "active" : null}
            name="contact"
          >
            Contact us
          </li>
          <li
            onClick={this.handleChangeTab}
            className={this.state.about ? "active" : null}
            name="about"
          >
            About
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement like this.

```
state = {
    selected: 1 // default selected tab 1(home)
}
handleChange = (tab) =>e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        selected: tab
    })
}

render (){
    return (
        <div>
        <ul className={styles.tabsResultsTabs}>
            <li onClick={this.handleChangeTab(1)} className={this.state.selected ===1? styles.active : null}>Home</li>    
            <li onClick={this.handleChangeTab(2)} className={this.state.selected===2 ? styles.active : null} id="2">Post</li>

            ...

        </ul>
    </div>
   )
}
```